# How to customize registration confirmation in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, html-email, registration

I'd like to customize a little bit Confirmation email template for new users in joomla 2.5

Currently it sends standard notifications like:

Hello USER,
Thank you for registering at WEBSITE. Your account is created and must be activated before you can use it.
To activate the account click on the following link or copy-paste it in your browser:
http://example.com/register?task=registration.activate&token=code

I'd like to add minor design styling to this email, for example - Add Background, and make the link as button.

Also, would be greate If I could send confirmation link to special created page for this.

Please assist me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registration message comes from Language Variable defined in com_users language file-

```
language\en-GB\en-GB.com_users.ini
```

You should search your message in the above file and create language override.

Please check the below link how to override langauge -

http://docs.joomla.org/Language_Overrides_in_Joomla

Comment: I changed body of message by including HTML tags, and DON'T FORGET to pass parameter $mode = TRUE (for HTML letters) in joomla sendMail() function - http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JUtility/sendMail

Comment: How do you pass the parameter $mode - TRUE?